# Truffle's Ganache VS Testrpc

Tags: testrpc, ganache

Is there any major difference between Truffle's Ganache and TestRPC? Do they run irrespective of each other as test blockchains, are there any side effects running both at same time? Is the only improvement that Ganache has a more handy ui?

Answer (score 18):

Ganache is TestRPC, it is like a rebranding. The github repo for ethereumjs-testrpc now redirects to ganache-cli.

As of today 2017-12-20 if you install through npm, both `npm install ethereumjs-testrpc` and `npm install ganache-cli` will install the same application.

You can launch both at the same time, but you have to select a different port for the second instance (only one instance can listen from port 8545).

Comment: FYI - a genache is a whipped filling of chocolate and cream, used in confectioneries such as cakes and [truffles](http://truffleframework.com/ganache/). :)

Comment: Is it Ganache instead of genache? . I believe it was a typo @Herald

Comment: Yes, the correct term is [ganache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ganache).

Answer (score 1):

TestRPC is now GANACHE-CLI, see this link https://www.trufflesuite.com/blog/testrpc-is-now-ganache